# create a regex to match a number

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to match a number with the following criteria:
• Length 12
• First character must be a 8
• The remaining 11 must be numeric 0-9

This is what I'm trying, but it does not work:

```
$(".ValidarTelefono").keypress(function (e) {        
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (tecla == 8) return true;
    patron = /^8\d{12}$/;
    te = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(te);
});
```

Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Should it not be: `/^8\d{11}$/`

Comment: Have a look at the value of `te`. Is that really what you want to test? I believe you want `return patron.test(this.value)` instead. Don't create implicit global variables. Always use `var` to declare your variables.

Comment: @Egor Yes, it is with 11, but it does not work :(

Comment: So are you trying to test to see if the entire value of a field matches the number pattern, every time a new character is entered?  Because a single key code is never going to be 12 characters long (which is what you are currently testing).

Answer (score 2):

the regexp seems correct, but
you are testing single char against it, not the whole string.

Comment: That's what I do. I want to see every time I click

Comment: @Eduardo: *"That's what I do."* What exactly do you think you are doing?

Comment: @Felix, sorry my level of english its very very bad

Comment: each time this function is called tecla contains only the one latest character entered -- it does not contain the whole string, so the regex can never match

Comment: @John then, how can i do?

Comment: @Eduardo your english is ok, you should test the whole incomplete input field content against regexp '8' then no more than 11 digits /^8\d{0,11}/ on every keystroke, not the last char only. You need DFA to test per-char

Comment: Perhaps what you want to test the regex against is:  $(this).val()

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines:

```
$(".ValidarTelefono").keypress(function (e) {        
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (tecla == 8) return true;
    patron = /^8\d{11}$/;
    var te = $(this).val() ;
    return patron.test(te);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the following:

```
$(".ValidarTelefono").keypress(function (e) {        
    patron = /^8\d{11}$/;
    if (patron.test($(this).val())) {
        . . . DO SOMETHING . . .
    }
    else {
        . . . DO SOMETHING ELSE . . .
    }
});
```

What that code should do is check to see if the current value of the field is a 12-digit number that begins with 8, every time a key is pressed in the field.

You don't want to return the result of the `.test()`, since, everytime it fails, it will block the character from being entered into the field.

---

**EDIT :** It occured to me that you might be trying to block any character that would not result in the creation of a 12-digit character, that begins with 8 . . . that code would be a little different:

First, controle the length of the number from within the text input by adding the `maxlength = 12` attribute.

Then, use the following code to check the characters:

```
$(".ValidarTelefono").keypress(function (e) {        
    var tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (tecla == 8) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        var te = String.fromCharCode(tecla);

        if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
            return (te === "8");
        }
        else {
            var patron = /\d/;
            return patron.test(te);
        }
    }
});
```

That being said, there are some **BIG** problems with this approach.  You put a lot of restrictions on what the user can do with their keyboard.  They can use `Backspace` to delete, but the can't use `Delete` . . . the can't use the arrow keys or `Home` or `End` to change the cursor position, they can't use `Ctrl-V` to paste in a valid value, etc.

I would be **VERY** hesitant to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Eduardo, you have to check the keydown and blur events, take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddanone/9faz7tbm/)

```
Teléfono: <input class="ValidarTelefono">

$(".ValidarTelefono").keypress(function (e) {        
    var tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (tecla == 8) return true;
    var patron = /^8[0-9]{0,12}$/;
    var te = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    var v=$(this).val()+te;
    console.log(v);
    return patron.test(v);
}).on("blur",function(){
    var patron = /^8[0-9]{12}$/;
    if(!patron.test( $(this).val() )){
       console.log('mal');
    }else{
      console.log('ok');
    }
});
```

Comment: Also you have to check a possible "paste" with letters on blur:

Comment: Also you have to check a possible "paste" with letters on blur:

   if( isNaN( $(this).val()*1 ) )    $(this).val('');